# Is there anyway to stream data from Snowflake to Oracle other then informatica

Tags: database, oracle, streaming, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on requirement where I need to stream data from Snowflake to Oracle for some value added process.

Few method which I got to know is unload file to S3 then load to Oracle and other one is informatica.

But above two approaches require some effort so is there any simple way of streaming data from Snowflake to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake cannot connect directly to Oracle.  You'll need some tooling or code "in between" the two.

I came across this data migration tool the other day, and it appears to support both Snowflake and Oracle: https://github.com/markddrake/YADAMU---Yet-Another-DAta-Migration-Utility/releases/tag/v1.0

-Paul-